# Where is LLDB in the Visual Studio 2019 clang extension?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, clion, lldb

Visual Studio comes with built-in clang support that can be enabled when installing. I have installed that support and now have all the clang executables in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin`.

I'm not using Visual Studio for development but just its clang build chain, I'm using CLion instead. Building works fine, but I have trouble debugging. I cannot debug, even though CLion says that it uses the "Bundled LLDB"; something just seems to go wrong, but CLion doesn't tell me what.

I have the suspicion that it somehow chose the wrong LLDB, so I wanted to check whether I can debug in the shell. But then I realized, that I am unable to locate that "bundled LLDB" CLion is mentioning. There is no `lldb.exe` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin`. In fact, I couldn't find an `lldb` in any subdirectory of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community`. So where is the debugger for Visual Studio 2019 clang? Or which other debugger could I use? Could I use the native MSVC debugger instead? If yes, where is this one located?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to build it yourself. From [the website](https://lldb.llvm.org/index.html):

> (*) Support for Windows is under active development. Basic
> functionality is expected to work, with functionality improving
> rapidly. ARM and AArch64 support is more experimental, with more known
> issues than the others.